# Why :after does not work in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-content

I am trying to give the following style:

```
.myclass{content: "\2a";}
```

it works in all browsers except `IE8`.

In `IE8` as well, it works on giving alerts.
I think its trying to apply style before the element is loaded.
How do I deal with it?

I tried:

```
$(".myclass").append($('<style>.ui-icon-closethick:after { content: " *" }</style>'));
```

But, this also did not work.

Comment: can you please create fiddle or stack snippet ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `::after`?

Comment: The jQuery won't work. `<style>` elements go in the `<head>`, not `<body>`.

Comment: @Barmar It was `:after` in IE 8, but IE 9 and up differentiate between pseudo-classes (`:`) and pseudo-elements (`::`).